# "Example for" vs. "Example of"

Tags: meaning-in-context, paraphrasing

> In 1923, Hesse settled in Switzerland, where he had been living for the past ten years and remained until his death in 1962. There he adopted a stance of detachment from political struggles, **which he presented as an example for Europe’s beleaguered intelligentsia**. But what was the positive content of his vision, if any? Did it serve any impulse higher than an anxious need for peace and quiet? These are questions Decker does not answer.

When it says “presented as an example ***for***”, what the text referring? Why doesn’t it say example ***of***? Why is it saying example ***for***?

Answer (score 6):

"**Example of**" is used when describing **the category or concept being illustrated by the example**. "Beer is an example of an alcoholic beverage" means that beer is one alcoholic beverage out of several possibilities.

"**Example for**" is used to indicate **who or what will be shown the example**. "I drew this picture of a lobster as an example for my brother, because he did not know what a lobster looked like."

In your quoted sentence, Hesse's detachment from political struggles is an example of how he believes the intelligentsia should behave.